# Distribution of inter-arrival time of non-homogenous Poisson Process

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales, poisson-distribution, poisson-process

What is the distribution of inter-arrival time of a non-homogenous Poisson Process?

In other words, if $T_n$ is a non-homogeneous Poisson process with intensity $\lambda(s)$, and $S_{n+1} = T_{n+1} - T_n$, what is
$$
\mathbb{P}[S_{n+1} > t]?
$$

What I  got:

$$\mathbb{P}[S_1\leq t] = 1 - \mathbb{P}[S_1> t]=\mathbb{P}[N_t=0]=1-e^{m_t} $$
with $m_t=\int_0^t\lambda(s)ds$

Therefore, $f_{S_1}(t)=\lambda(t)e^{-m_t}$

$$\mathbb{P}[S_2\leq t] = \int_0^\infty\mathbb{P}[S_2\leq t| S_1=s]f_{S_1}(t)ds=\int_0^\infty\lambda(s)e^{-m_{t+s}}ds$$

Is this correct? If yes, what would be: $$
\mathbb{P}[S_{n+1} > t]
$$

Comment: conditioned on what?

Comment: P(S_n+1>t | N(T_n)=n)) where S_n+1= T_(n+1)-T_(n)

Comment: If $T_n$ is the $n^{\mathrm{th}}$ arrival time, isn't $N(T_n)=n$ by definition?